# C# List, Removing all null values *after* last non-null element

Tags: c#, .net, list, winforms, linq

I have a list of strings, example(C#):

```
new List<string> { "string1", null, null "string2", "string3", null, null, null }
```

I have many of those, all with different amounts of strings and nulls, where every one can be in a different place and the list length is not the same for each list, also not necessarily string list.

How would I remove the remaining null values after the last string, after the last non null value, keeping the null values that are between and in front of?

Thanks!

/Fredman

Comment: Process the list backwards and remove them?...

Comment: `if (list has a non-null item) { while (last item is null) { remove last item }} `?

Comment: If the list has length of 5 **and all entries are `null`** should they all be removed?

Comment: mjwills: I used `tempList.All(texture => texture == null)` to determine if all values are null, if so the list isn't added to a Dictionary and forgotten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your list from last item to the beginning and remove null values until a non null values is reached:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "string1", null, null "string2", "string3", null, null, null };

for(int i=list.Count - 1; i>=0; i--)
{
     if(list[i]==null) list.RemoveAt(i);
     else break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid iterating the list twice to determine whether all entries are `null` (as you are currently doing), I'd suggest a slight tweak of Ashkan's solution:

```
var list = new List<string> { "string1", null, null, "string2", "string3", null, null, null };

int? firstNonNullIndex = null;

for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (list[i] != null)
    {
        firstNonNullIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (firstNonNullIndex == null) {
    // Do nothing as per your requirements (i.e. this handles your `All` call)
}
else
{
    list.RemoveRange(firstNonNullIndex.Value + 1, list.Count - firstNonNullIndex.Value - 1);
    // Do whatever you need to do with the `List` here
}
```

This solution has two main benefits:

- A single `RemoveRange` call is faster than multiple `Remove` calls
- No need to remove all (or indeed any!) of the elements if they are **all** `null` (i.e. this scenario gets much faster)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple way to remove all trailing `null` items:

```
while (items.Any() && items.Last() == null) items.RemoveAt(items.Count - 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Linq way:

```
int position = list.IndexOf(
          list.Where(x =>x!=null).OrderByDesc.FirstOrDefault());
return position == list.Count -1 ? list: list.RemoveRange(position+1, list.Count - 1);
```